# Insert A Variable in windows.location href Not Working

Tags: javascript, php

Have Find Some Examples in php but not in javascript
but its not work and i have search can not find any on web i have try the example but i tank so the way i did is not correct all my code:

I Have Try Already Few Different Ways Like This One But I Still Not Get This Code Work Correctly

```html
window.location.href = "<?php echo $up1; ?>"
```

```html
<?php
$up1 = $row['up1'];
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
mysql_real_escape_string($user_points);
mysql_real_escape_string($user_voucher);
mysql_real_escape_string($user_level);
mysql_real_escape_string($user_wallet);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT up1 FROM settings");
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$up1 = $up1;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div  id='exemple' data-up='<?php echo $up1;?>'>
 </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { 
    // enter key do nothing
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }      
}
</script>

<script>
        window.oncontextmenu = function () {
            console.log("Right Click Disabled");
            return false;
        }


    </script>



<script type="text/javascript"> 
function disableselect(e){  
return false  
}  

function reEnable(){  
return true  
}  

//if IE4+  
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")  
document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false")  
//if NS6  
if (window.sidebar){  
document.onmousedown=disableselect  
document.onclick=reEnable  
}
</script>


<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function goToBing() {
 //window.location.href = "<?php echo $up1; ?>"
var test=$("#exemple").attr('data-up);
   window.location.href=test;
}
</script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center><a href="http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt" onclick="goToBing();return false;">Click To Confirm Please</a></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is `$` in `$("#exemple")`? It is jquery? If yes - where's jQuery included in your code?

Comment: well i never used jquery and i have insert it on head section <head>
<div  id='exemple' data-up='<?php echo $up1;?>'>
 </div>

Comment: If you're sure that you included jquery (but i'm not), then open developer's console and check for errors there.

Comment: well i have made some search and i have place the code but i haven place the jquery solution on head tanks for the advise

Comment: well i have try to insert the jquery code on the head section it go on home page but not on the link were it should go

Comment: I Have See In Console And It Give Me That Error---> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)